# When using AWS EMR Step Spark-Submit how to get it to accept a path with a space

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to use from the AWS Console EMR steps with a space in the path but for some reason spark-submit does something odd and does not work when a space is introduced.

Command

```
spark-submit "s3://bucket/prefix with spaces/stepCode.py"
spark-submit 's3://bucket/prefix with spaces/stepCode.py'
spark-submit s3://bucket/prefix%with%spaces/stepCode.py
```

Error from AWS

```
python: can't open file '/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-3XXXXXXXXXXXX/s3:/bucket/prefix with spaces/stepCode.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However this works

```
spark-submit s3://bucket/nospaces/stepCode.py
```

and the code is dumped to the below somehow

```
/mnt/tmp/spark-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX/stepCode.py
```

Any idea on how get spark-submit to accept a path with a space in it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try by escaping `spaces` with **`backslash \`**

```
spark-submit s3://bucket/prefix\ with\ spaces/stepCode.py
```

Comment: It didn't work. It came back with error "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-XXXXXXXXXXX/s3:/mybucket/prefix%5C"

Comment: It is mean that the file is loaded but EMR cannot find the `main class`.

Comment: @lamanus that doesn't sound right given the error. Since the error is file:/.../s-XX/s3:/... instead of file:/.../s-XX/filename.py I think this 'could' mean that the file is being properly copying the file from s3 to the master core to be run, but instead of passing to the master core only the name of the file, it is passing the whole path when telling the master core to actually run the copied command.

Comment: Oh I see. Then try s3a please. I will test it today when I have some time.